# Get output confidence in binary classification with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

I am trying to build a really shallow binary classification network in Keras in order to discriminate between two domains.

I want to get the probability (or some sort of confidence score) for each prediction.

I read the data from folders like this:

```py
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('sim2city/train/', class_mode='binary', batch_size=32)
val_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('sim2city/val/', class_mode='binary', batch_size=32)
test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('sim2city/test/', class_mode='binary', batch_size=1)
```

I haven't done any other processing.
I tried to train something like this for 5 epochs:

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(256, 256, 3)),
      keras.layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    #keras.layers.Dense(16, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
   ])
```

then

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
predict = model.predict_generator(test_it, steps=NumImgs)
```

but the values of the results are 0/1 or 1/0, not something in between to be used as a confidence score. Also, for me it is pretty weird because the total accuracy is not 100%, so if it has some wrong classifications, I guess, at least, it should not be so sure of it.

Comment: This should simply be working as expected. If they're exact zeros or ones, you may be looking at the wrong variable, or you may be training too much.

Comment: Hint... try using `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` instead. The "sparse" losses transform the full tensors in pairs of location/value. Not sure it would change the model's outputs, but there might be some strange Keras doings there.

Comment: Gives probabilities for me - is your Keras up to date? Also, what's your code for `test_it`, and is your data normalized?

Comment: I added more information in the question, If needed, I can provide the whole code. I don't think I train it too much since the accuracy is around 95%.

Comment: I added datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255). Now it looks better. Do you think this was the problem?